# Getting error while opening file with gstreamer in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer, v4l2

I am getting error while opening file with gstreamer in opencv below is my pipeline. I have searched on internet any try all possible things but nothing is working for me.

ERROR

[ WARN:0] OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to query duration of stream
[ WARN:0] OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=1, value=1, duration=-1

```
cv::VideoCapture capture("filesrc location=a.mp4  ! qtdemux ! queue ! h264parse ! v4l2h264dec ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=GRAY8 ,width=1280,height=720 !  appsink",CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

Comment: Where is ```CAP_GSTREAMER``` at the end?

Comment: that was typo error i have corrected it

Comment: Try the GStreamer pipeline with `gst-launch-1.0` first.

Comment: with that it is working fine